# Error while running a 'glance image-create' command. "publicURL endpoint for image not found"

Tags: openstack

While issuing this command on ubuntu 14.02 Server edition.

```
glance image-create --name "cirros" --file cirros-0.3.3-x86_64-disk.img --disk-format qcow2 --container-format bare --is-public True --progress
```

I got the following error message:

```
"publicURL endpoint for image not found"
```

Following were the series of commands that I executed:

```
$ nano admin-openrc.sh
    export OS_TENANT_NAME=admin
    export OS_USERNAME=admin
    export OS_PASSWORD=XXXXXX
    export OS_AUTH_URL=http://controller:35357/v2.0

$ source admin-openrc.sh
$ wget -P /tmp/images http://download.cirros-cloud.net/0.3.3/cirros-0.3.3-x86_64-disk.img
$ glance image-create --name "cirros-0.3.3-x86_64" --file /tmp/images/cirros-0.3.3-x86_64-disk.img --disk-format qcow2 --container-format bare --is-public True --progress
```

Please help...

Many thanks in advance.

--V

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the problem, by hashing out identity_uri like this :

```
[keystone_authtoken]
auth_host = controller
auth_port = 35357
auth_protocol = http
auth_uri = http://controller:5000/v2.0
#identity_uri = http://controller:35357
admin_tenant_name = service
admin_user = nova
admin_password = openstack
```